# The file 'wp-config.php' already exists?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a copy of and edited the wp-config-sample.php file with all of the database details that should be in it (obtained from my host, and also created in mamp pro data user).

I have also replaced the unique phrases and corrected all $ with S as suggested by WordPress forum, forums here and tutorials.

I also then saved it as wp-config.php as suggested. When I then go to Wordpress and say submit it says that the file already exists.

In my Wordpress folder there is both the original sample file and the edited one I was asked to either create or edit. If I delete the sample page and submit it says I am missing a wp-config.php and need to create it. I put it back and it says the file already exists. I then edited the wp-config-sample.php file and just corrected the name as wp-config.php and still nothing I try or change works.

**(I solved this problem as my root password in mamp pro was not the same as in the wp.config file, as soon as I had that corrected it all fell into place and worked :-))**

Comment: I am not sure I really follow what is going on but one thing that occurs to me is permissions. Check that the files you are playing with have the right owner. If you are doing stuff through Wordpress it will have the permissions that your web server runs as.

Comment: @PhilWallach...I know its a lot to ask but in this very useful tutorial [Link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_y0Gmsfqro&index=33&list=WL) it explains step by step on how to setup WordPress in Dreamweaver using Mamp Pro to test locally and run multiple wordpress sites.  In this next link [Link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2-U4nKZ2oM) it shows you if you have a problem on editing the wp-config-sample.php how to edit it so it will work.   I have followed all these steps as suggested. I also went to wordpress.org help forum, and what ever I could get there I did too. But nothing is helping

Comment: @ArshidKK...let me go try that and see if it helps. thanks to you both.

Comment: ok .. Just delete **wp-config.php** and open  `http://yourwebsite/`  or localhost. Then install and enter database details.

Comment: @ArshidKK..Okay I have deleted wp-config.php in wordpress folder..and this is where I go to, to get the wordpress details to fill in to submit.Link (http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1) .. Am I understanding you correctly? Am I right so far?

Comment: @ArshidKK .. I think I have done as you suggested and it gives me this error... (Sorry, but I can’t write the wp-config.php file. You can create the wp-config.php manually and paste the following text into it.) This is what I am battling with.

Comment: @ArshidKK ..Then I go to the wp-config-sample.php and I change it to wp-config.php as it has all the changed data base user ect. (because its asking to either edit or create it)..then I safe it as they suggest. They do not mention to delete the sample.php which means they are both in the wordpress folder, if you take one or the other out, it still gives an error message that differs...I don't understand this..

Comment: To everybody here my apologies for all my bad posts..I'm not good at posting as you all have noticed :( .. But I am trying my best :( .. if I come up with a solution I will post it here for future users that might have the same problem.

Comment: where are you getting the error "already exists"?

Comment: Please create new database in phpadmin. Then try ..

Comment: @David..sorry I was at work, I just got home, will check and let you  know asap.

Comment: @ArshidKK..i will try anything to solve this, will also do and get back to you asap.

Comment: My problem was not knowing enough of wordpress that time to understand how the wp-config file actually worked. The reason why this wp-config file was not working with the details that I had put into it, was because I did not double check my root password in mamp pro :-) ... the password I thought it was all in lower case, actually had to be uppercase. It took me this long to realize this very small mistake. But, none the less, a good lesson learned. I have now gone over to DesktopServer (ServerPress) as it is simpler to understand and easier to work if in noob mode. :-)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i am not allowed to comment, but are you developing on a local machine or through a web hosting? I believe your in Mac. The safe bet here would be, for you, to delete the wordpress folder in the htdocs directory, untar it again there, and from the browser go to *localhost/wordpress-folder-name* and follow the wizard. (open up *localhost/phpmyadmin* to setup MySQL database)

If you want to put the wordpress in a live web host, then use ftp to upload the wordpress directory (you will have to change the settings). So, actually, unzipping a fresh copy of wordpress directly, and following the wordpress setup wizard online would be easy. For the MySQL database, use the settings provided by the host.

In these steps, you never have to touch the wp-config-sample.php nor wp-config.php file.

Comment: Hi sorry I am taking so long to solve this, but I am getting there, I have so much work in-between having trouble to solve this. Will be soon. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I FINNALY got the hang of how this wp-config works, not understanding what wordpress was about so long ago, it was IMPOSSIBLE to even try and explain what I was not understanding. :-D But I have explained why I had this problem above. Thank you all for your patience :-)